# What am I doing wrong when modify a JSON List object and writing it to file?

Tags: c#, json, discord, discord.net

My JSON list looks like this,(Where Type 3 is the CommandType.Welcome):

```
[
  {
    "Keyword": "Hello",
    "Type": 0,
    "Message": "World"
  },
  {
    "Keyword": "Hi",
    "Type": 0,
    "Message": "There"
  },
  {
    "Keyword": "Test",
    "Type": 0,
    "Message": "test"
  },
  {
    "Keyword": "Greeting",
    "Type": 3,
    "Message": "Welcome"
  }
]
```

My current method will pull the correct Object from the list and modify the object but it isn't modify the List Object and therefore will not modify the file. For Example, command.message = message but when I serialize the list it doesn't merge the changes.

```
    public void SetGreetMessage(string message)
    {
        var leaveGreet = new LeaveGreetService();
        foreach (var command in leaveGreet.CommandList.Where(x => x.Type == CommandType.Welcome))
        {
            command.Message = message;
            dynamic jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CommandList, Formatting.Indented);

            File.WriteAllText("Commands.txt", jsonData);
        }
    }
```

I have looked online at a few resources and most parse into a string and modify it with the string. But I was wondering if it was possible to do it like this somehow. I know I can add a new object to it with this method but modifying seems to be a great feat.

```
using System;

namespace vVvBot.Model
{
    public class CustomCommand
    {
        public string Keyword { get; set; }
        public CommandType Type { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

    public enum CommandType
    {
        Message,
        Faq,
        Action,
        Welcome,
        Leaving
    }
}
```

CommandList is the list of the command Object from the file

Comment: why use `dynamic`

Comment: You're writing CommandList (every time you find a match, BTW) but you're actually looping through and modifying leaveGreet  which you've newly created and which might not have anything in it.

Comment: @RayFischer It's bad coding, but its only going to hit it once in its current state. I recently set it to that for testing.

Comment: And you're still modifying one object and writing a different object.

Comment: @RayFischer How would I go about modifying the Command List then sending it to the file

Comment: I fixed the issue. I needed to index where it was and edit the commandList Directly. Thank you